# How to append the dataframe output to .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

[image: TI_Binning]

I wanted to extract specific data from my excel sheet and save & append these data to my existing .txt file. My current code is below, but i'm getting error in saving the data to txt file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\a0229010\Desktop\PP177507.xls", 'TI_Binning', skiprows=2)
df = df.iloc[:, [6, 7]]

import numpy as np

with open(r"C:\Users\a0229010\Desktop\TI_Bin.txt", "ab") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, df)  #this is the line where i am getting the error
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: try changing the mode of the file object to 'w' or 'a' instead of 'ab', 'w' will overwrite the existing file and 'a' will append the new data to the existing file.
`with open(r"C:\Users\a0229010\Desktop\TI_Bin.txt", "w") as f: 
    np.savetxt(f, df, delimiter=',')`

Comment: tried to do your suggested code but getting this Type error: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e')

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the filtered dataframe to string using `df.to_string()` and write it in a text file. You can also pass `index=False` inside `to_string()` if you do not need index in the text file.

Here is an example for you :-

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, [6, 7]]

with open("try.txt",'a') as fa :
    fa.write(df1.to_string(index=False))
```

Here is an image of the sample data that I am using :-

[image]

Here is the output in the text file :-

[image]